# Elementor not show column in mobile

Tags: mobile, wordpress-theming, elementor

I installed Hello Elementor, then imported a header from library, it’s desktop layout like picture one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlYmj.png)

And it’s mobile layout like picture two.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNT9i.png)

I want to show telephone and email on mobile, but whatever I tried, it still only showing social and search

- What factors determine mobile will show which column ?
- I tried **hide/delete** social and search for mobile in responsive, **it become blank**, still not show the telephone and email ?

Any hints to fix this problem, thanks

I tried :

1. hide columns for mobile
2. narrow columns
3. delete other columns

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to solve this not seeing what it looks like in the editor or in the inspector but if this is time-sensitive and you are looking for a quick fix, I would recommend hiding that entire container on mobile and adding a new container with email and phone number only and then hiding that on desktop and tablet.

Hope this helps!